# Run multiple commands in watch

Tags: bash, watch

I have a small script, that I want to constantly run until I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I saw a few suggestions of using `watch`, and the small examples I've seen work fine, but I can't get it to work for me.

Here's my script

```
echo -en "\nQueued forks: "$(( $(ls -lash /var/www/data/forked/* | wc -l) - 10 ));
echo -en "\nRunning fork processes: "$(ps -ef | awk '$8 ~ /jsfork*/ {print}' | wc -l)"\n\n";
ps auxfww;

if [ -e /var/www/data/logs/fork.log ]
then
    echo -en "\n\nErrors:\n"
    more /var/www/data/logs/fork.log
else
    echo -en "\n\nNo errors.\n\n"
fi
```

All the examples I've seen have been roughly `watch -n x 'do something'`, but since my script has `'` in it, it didn't work just wrapping it around.

Is there anyway I can use `watch` with my script?

I'm not sure if OS makes much of a difference in this case, but it's running on Ubuntu 12

Comment: Place your script in a file, make it executable and provide it as an argument to `watch`.

Comment: Anything more than a straightforward two or three commands would be better in a script. Even if it's in `/tmp` and thrown away after use.

Comment: Ahh good idea, just did that and it works great. If you wanna post that as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @roaima Is that just down to readability, or is there a technical reason why that would be a better approach too?

Comment: Practicality. It is possible to escape quotes inside quotes but it gets very messy. My personal take is that if it gets that complicated it's probably easier just to throw the commands in a script and `watch` that.

Comment: Very good point, I didn't think about quotes (even though that's the exact problem I had haha!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply place the commands in a file, prepend a shebang (`#!/bin/sh`), make it executable (`chmod +x script.sh`) and provide it as argument to `watch`:

```
watch ./script.sh
```